# Tomcat is not running even though JAVA_HOME path is correct

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, windows-7, java-home

When I am trying to run tomcat using `startup.bat` I get the following error,

```
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE
```

But then I try `C:\>echo %java_home%` and I get the following result

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
```

I have even tried setting `JAVA_HOME` manually to system variable list, but this issue remains.

What can I do to solve it?

I am using Windows 7.

---

### Update

After setting a new system variable named JAVA_HOME and setting its path to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin\"`, I tried the start up script again and this time I get a new error.

```
D:\Work\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin>startup.bat
Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25"" was unexpected at this time.
```

Any idea what this error means?

I even tried setting the path to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\"`(that is without **bin**) but same error occurs.

Comment: Check if startup.bat is redefining that environment variable. Look for "SET JAVA_HOME ... "

Comment: @luciano no, there is no re-definition of JAVA_HOME.

Comment: are there any spaces in your JAVA_HOME? Also did you get your echo result correctly or is it just a copy/paste mistake?

Comment: @zenzen yes, it was c/p mistake. I have updated the question as well.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Try installing java somewhere else - in a directory without spaces. Set again the `JAVA_HOME` variable and try again. I remember Tomcat had some problems on Window XP with spaces if any variables it was using while starting contained spaces. Maybe it's similar with Windows 7.

I remember I had to change some lines in Tomcat java classes which were handling Tomcat startup.

**@Edit:** Luciano beat me to noticing it but you should also remove `bin` from `JAVA_HOME`

**@Edit:** I also remember that another fix (didn't test it myself, though) was to set `JAVA_HOME` to the shorthand version e.g. `C:\Progra~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`

Comment: If you see my updated question I think you have just hit it. `Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25` means its the last part of `Program Files`. So, I guess its white space issue. Is there any escape character that I can use in the path to solve this, without going to install/uninstall.

Comment: I think its a tomcat issue. What makes you think its related to windows?

Comment: Because it works on *NIX systems :) From what I remember there's a line in one of the java classes written by Tomcat guys which doesn't properly handle spaces, so yeah it kinda is a Tomcat issue but only on Windows systems, if I remember correctly.

Comment: Problem solved I re installed on a different location without white space. This is very annoying when a high profile product has this type of messy issues.

Comment: Just to clarify to other users coming to this site, that the JDK can be perfectly installed on a path that contains white spaces and Tomcat runs just fine using it.

Comment: I get this same issue and I have no spaces in either JAVA_HOME not PATH.

Comment: @Luciano I can verify Luciano's comment. I just had the same issue as the OP and I am using Tomcat 7.0.47 with JRE 1.7.0. I took the quotes out of my CATALINA_HOME, CATALINA_BASE, and JRE_HOME (no JDK installed on this box). Taking the quotes off let me run Tomcat with the following command: `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\startup.bat `

Comment: Using the "no-spaces" version of the path works great. Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 19):

I think that your JAVA_HOME should point to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25
```

instead of

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
```

That is, without the **bin** folder.

**UPDATE**

That new error appears to me if I set the JAVA_HOME with the quotes, like you did. Are you using quotation marks? If so, remove them.

Comment: If you know its *the* right thing, then why would it make you *think*? :P

Comment: I find it more politely to say it that way.

Comment: I am using tomcat 7.0.62. The only change that I had to make was to install latest version of JRE and after that everything worked smoothly. I installed jre1.8.0_60 and the problem got solved.

Comment: @Luciano - This is really late to comment on your comment, but when you say "I think" just to be "polite", you are actually saying (to many readers) that you are not certain of the answer.  This causes the reader to doubt your answer ... which is a bad thing (if it is in fact correct).  In writing StackOverflow answers, it is more important to be clear than to be polite.  (And besides, in many cultures, saying "I think ..." has no connotations of politeness or modesty at all.)  In short, Quazi makes a valid point.

Answer (score 9):

Avoid semicolon in the end of any environment variables... from JAVA_HOME or JRE_HOME

```
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_25\bin
```

and

```
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\jre
```

should be like as shown...

Answer (score 6):

I had Win 8 x86 installed. My `Path` variable had entry `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin` and I also had following variables:

- `JAVA_HOME` : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31;`
- `JRE_HOME` : `C:\Program Files\Java\jre6;`

My tomcat is installed at `C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\apache-tomcat-7.0.41`

And still it did not worked for me.

I tried by replacing `Program Files` in those paths with `Progra~1`. I also tried by moving JAVA to another folder so that full path to it does not contain any spaces. But nothing worked.

Finally environment variables that worked for me are:

- Kept path variable as is with full `Program Files` i.e. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin`
- `JAVA_HOME` : `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31`
- Deleted `JRE_HOME`

So what I did is removed `JRE_HOME` and removed semicolon at the end of `JAVA_HOME`. I think semicolon should not be an issue, though I removed it. I am giving these settings, since after a lot of googling nothing worked for me and suddenly these seem to work. You can replicate and see if it works for you.

This also worked for Win 7 x64, where

- Path variable contained `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin`
- `JAVA_HOME` is set to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_17` (without semicoln)

Please tell me why this worked, I know removing `JRE_HOME` was weird solution, but any guesses what difference it makes?

Comment: As said for me the same, finally your solution got worked

Answer (score 2):

Remove the 'bin' from JAVA_HOME. That solves the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Set Environment Variable ([Windows Key]+[Pause Key], switch to "Advanced", click "Environment Variables", in "System Variables" (lower list), click "New" (or "Edit" if you already have it),

name:
JAVA_HOME

value:
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3

for C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32

click "ok",

go to "path" in "system variables",

add ; at the end of the line (unless there is already one there),

add: 
C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK16~1.0_3\bin

click "ok" through all. -- restart your computer (advisable)

Answer (score 0):

I set the

variable name : JAVA_HOME 
value   : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32

I set these properties in system/environment variables without semicolon, tomcat is running on my system.

It really works.

Answer (score 0):

Also ensure that you have the correct version of Tomcat for the CPU type.  I had installed a 64bit tomcat on a 32bit O/S but it was giving me the JAVA_HOME exception when that wasn't the case at all.

Answer (score 0):

there are two types of environment variable 
first User variable if you path in this it will work for that particular user only.
second is System variable if you set path in this it is used by all type of users..
In my system i set JAVA_HOME in system variable,it was not working,then i set path in 
User variable it is working.....so try in both type of environment variable...

Answer (score 0):

Some times semiColon makes matter
 please ensure

```
JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32
```

but not

```
JAVA_HOME=c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32;
```

Same problem i got but not solved

Answer (score 0):

Set environment variables for JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME without the \bin.
That worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the Tomcat and unzipped it again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

To run Tomcat8 you need to have JRE_HOME defined in Env Variable.

JAVA_HOME alone will not do even if correctly set.

```
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_77\jre
```

You should select the JRE that is inside SDK, i.e. one with your JDK(SDK) installation.
In other words your JAVA_HOME + \jre

When compiling JDK is needed to support JSP, to compile Servlets which are generated from *.jsp files. Otherwise to run JRE is needed. So when you develop you need JAVA_HOME and when you deploy you need JRE_HOME.

Answer (score 0):

For reference for me with Atlassian's Bamboo the issue was because I had wrapped the command in speech marks

So

```
SET JRE_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121"
```

Was wrong, where as the right version is

```
SET JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121
```

This gave me the error message

```
Files\Java\jre1.8.0_121"" was unexpected at this time.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the comparability, if you are using java 8 then use tomcat 9, if you are using java 7 then use tomcat 7. and also set the JAVA_HOME till C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101, not with bin.

Answer (score -1):

```
First Run the tomcat directly through the tomcat /bin folder with 
startup.bat if running sucessful the set the variable as below sample
```

JAVA_HOME value : C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32;

path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\bin;

CATALINA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.27 ;

PATH=%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin;

***if needed*** CLASS_PATH:%CATALINA_HOME%\lib;%JAVA_HOME%\lib;

Comment: previous answer was unacceptable . Thanks for the Suggestion.

Answer (score -1):

Remove semicolon and you can see that link:
http://www.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Tomcat_HowTo.html

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Just put the essential parts of the link in your answer

Answer (score -2):

I had similar problem and please note that we need not set JAVA_HOME unless we are going to use debug mode.
tomcat in windows 7 can handle spaces in environment variables
the problem is because of "bin" in the path.
setting JRE_HOME to C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_65 solved my problem and tomcat is up and running without any trouble