# The CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly

Tags: configuration, tomcat7, catalina

I know there is exact thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9361623/catalina-home-environmental-variable-is-not-defined-correctly). But am not finding any solution on that page. I `cd` to bin directory of Tomcat folder and ran startup.bat. And got this error.

I echoed the environment variables below and I think they are correctly set. What could be the problem here?

[image]

Comment: well I did not fixed this problem, but then I reinstalled and somehow the setup I explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19098377/1317018) worked. Because of lots of params like Windows / Java / Tomcat versions, you can just see if you can mimick these settings. Mostly it will work.