# Tomcat 8 startup.bat is not running(direct Run) but working in Eclipse JAVA_HOME path is correct

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, web

I am not able to run my tomcat server directly through command prompt(Using startup.bat).But it is running fine in eclipse.I verified my JAVA_HOME path which set correctly.How to solve this issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tomcat is not running even though JAVA\_HOME path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858711/tomcat-is-not-running-even-though-java-home-path-is-correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We need to set CATALINA_HOME also in environment variables.Add the below entries in environmental variables

```
CATALINA_HOME
D:\apache-tomcat-8.0.41

JAVA_HOME
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Tomcat 7 (might be applicable to Earlier versions too) 
open catalina.bat in a text editor modify the EXECJAVA variable from 
""start %_RUNJAVA%"" to just ""%_RUNJAVA%"" . 
run startup.bat from a command window instead of double clicking it and 
see what error it is pointing.

Also, check the JRE_HOME variable.