# Installing/running apache tomcat

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

New guy here! I need to install Apache Tomcat (among other things such as Java JDK and Eclipse) for a class. After downloading Java JDK (jdk1.8.0_152), I downloaded the Apache zip file (version 8.5.24) and transfered it to "Program Files". I then created the system variable "JAVA_HOME" (JAVA_HOME : "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152"). When I tried to run the startup.bat in the command-line interface, it didn't worked and referred to the CATALINA_HOME variable not being defined. I then created the CATALINA_HOME variable (CATALINA_HOME : "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.24"). After that, when I try to run the startup.bat (I used this line : "C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.24\bin\startup.bat"), I get Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.24"" was unexpected. That where I am at the moment... I looked into the forum and I am wondering if I am missing something in the Path variable. I also looked into this question ([Tomcat is not running even though JAVA_HOME path is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858711/tomcat-is-not-running-even-though-java-home-path-is-correct)), but it didn't solved my problem.

Thanks!

**Update**

In my opinion, the other question was not exactly the same as mine (even though they are very similar) and the solution for me was also different. Running the startup.bat in the command line center was not working. Creating shortcuts solved my solution. Thank you all!

Comment: You must escape the space in "Program Files". Try to put a **doublequotes**  for `"Program Files"` in all your paths.

Comment: I highly recommend installing Tomcat outside the `Program Files` folder for two reasons: 1) Tomcat doesn't like spaces in the file path. 2) UAC (User Account Control) restrictions on the `Program Files` folder may interfere.

Comment: As others said, keep the path to Tomcat short and sweet, with no spaces. On a Unix machine, I put it in the home folder for that reason. I suggest the equivalent on Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem solution at first sight should fix above answer. But there are other ways to fix it too.

You can also put the `%CATALINA_HOME%/bin;` in `PATH` variable. Than you can run `$startup.bat` command from terminal/console directly without giving any full path. In this case you will have to restart the terminal (command prompt) window.

Another handy feature is to create shortcut of `startup.bat` file in `Desktop` (may be) and just run it.

Comment: Creating shortcuts solved my problem! I was then able to connect apache with Eclipse. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear. Welcome!!

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the space in "Program Files" messes up everything. Try adding the path surrounded with quotes. If that doesnt work you could move Tomcat directory to another place (which path does not contain spaces)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I moved the Tomcat and the Java directory to another place with no spaces, but still get the Files\apache-tomcat-8.5.24"" was unexpected. I also changed the variables (JAVA_HOME and CATALINA_HOME) to match the new location.

Comment: Did you now updated your command? Suppose you are using Windows OS and you have placed the `apache-tomcat` under `C` drive. Now the path should change to new location.